# React Native custom TextInput component has turquoise indicator on hold

Tags: react-native

I made a custom TextInput component, which cursor color was also `turquoise`, but with the `selectionColor Prop` I managed to change its color. If I hold my finger on the input field, this indicator shows up, having turquoise color from nowhere. Not a single component has this color in the application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check this github issue, you will get the solution of above problem
https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/344